# How to redirect in NextJS if not logged using nextAuth

Tags: redirect, next.js, next-auth

I am using nextAuth for authentication in my project and I would like to restrict certain pages for the clients that are not logged in.

I tried calling the `useSession()` hook in the `getServerSideProps()` function but I got an error for calling the hook there.

Is it possible to do a redirect on the server side using nextAuth?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't use the useSession hook in getServerSideProps. You need to use getSession. You can read more [here](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#server-side). You can redirect in getServerSideProps if the session doesn't exist. Here's an example:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const session = await getSession(context)

  if (!session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    }
  }

  return {
    props: { session }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Feb 2023**: With the new **app/ directory feature coming with NextJS13**, the auth middleware from NextAuth isn't working (at least for me).

I figured out a way to protect frontend sites easily and fast.
But be aware that it is bad practice to protect only your frontend pages! Your API should be secured too!

Here's the code:

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from "pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]"
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export default async function Page() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
  if(session == null){
    return redirect("api/auth/signin")
  } else {
    return (
      <>
      <h1 className=" text-2xl">Very secure Page</h1>  
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(session, null, 2)}</pre>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the `middleware.ts`  file is on the same directory level as your app folder and pages folder

Comment: wow, this works. how tragic.

Comment: This works and it's the approach I'm currently using but the issue is that you get server side errors because the redirect includes a HEAD request and that causes next auth to throw an UnknownAction error. Mostly just annoying since the rest of the flow works as intended.

Answer (score 3):

NextAuth can handle redirection to a sign-in page if the user is not logged in. Take a look at the [documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#nextjs-middleware)

Here are the steps

1. Create a file called middleware.ts on the same directory level as your `pages` folder or your `app` folder if you are using next js 13
2. You can export a config object inside middleware.ts that has a matcher property assigned to an array of the routes you want to protect. In the example below I am protecting all routes that start with /admin. But you can add as many as you want since it is an array.

middleware.ts

```
 export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

 export const config = {
  matcher: ["/admin/:path*"],
};
```

Comment: This does not work in Next 13 and app directory. I do not have a solution.,=

Answer (score 1):

Recommended to use middleware approach now:
https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#server-side

Answer (score 0):

**Aug 2023 Update:** The method `getSession()` has been replaced by `getServerSession()`. Here is an example of how to protect Server-side rendered pages:

```
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from "./api/auth/[...nextauth]"
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"

export default function Page() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  if (typeof window === "undefined") return null

  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Protected Page</h1>
        <p>You can view this page because you are signed in.</p>
      </>
    )
  }
  return <p>Access Denied</p>
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      session: await getServerSession(
        context.req,
        context.res,
        authOptions
      ),
    },
  }
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#server-side).